# The radical of $kG$-modules

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modular-representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\Rad{Rad}$Let $k$ be a finite field of $p$ elements. Let $G$ be an elementary abelian p-group and $V$ a $kG$-module corresponding to the representation $\alpha:G\rightarrow \mathrm{GL}_{n}(k)$. Denote the radical of $V$ by $\Rad(V)$ which is defined to be the intersection of all maximal submodules of $V$. Note that $\Rad^{i}(V)=\Rad(  \Rad^{i-1}(V) )$. Now, let $s<p$ and suppose that $(\alpha(g)-1)^{s}=0$ for all   $ g \in G $ . In fact, I'd conjecture that $\Rad^{s}(V)=0$. I think we should start  from the case  $ s=p-1$ but I don't know how to do this.

I would appreciate any hints and comments. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question is whether, if $(g - 1)^s$ acts as zero on a module $V$ for every group element $g$, where $s<p$, then $\operatorname{Rad}^s(V)=0$. This is false for $s=p$, so the condition $s<p$ is crucial.

Comment: The question is equivalent to the question of whether $\{ (g - 1)^s \mid g\in G\}$ generates $\operatorname{Rad}^s(kG)$ as an ideal of $kG$.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is yes: $\text{Rad}(kG)^s$ is generated as an ideal by $(g-1)^s$ for $G$ an elementary abelian $p$-group and $s \leq p-1$.

**Lemma**: Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space and let $s \leq p-1$. Then $\text{Sym}^s(V)$ is spanned by the elements $v^s$ for $v \in V$.

**Proof:** $\text{Sym}^s(V)$ is clearly spanned by products of the form $v_1 v_2 \cdots v_s$. We have
$$v_1 v_2 \cdots v_s = \frac{1}{s!} \sum_{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_s \in \{ 0,1 \}} (-1)^{s-\sum c_i} (c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_s v_s)^s.$$
We used that $s \leq p-1$ in order to be allowed to divide by $s!$. $\square$

We now answer the question. Let $(g_i)_{i \in I}$ be a set of generators for $G$ and put $t_i = g_i-1$. Then $kG \cong k[t_i : i \in I]/\langle t_i^p : i \in I  \rangle$. The radical $R$ is the ideal $\langle t_i \rangle$. We want to show that $R^s$ is generated by the elements $(1-\prod_i g_i^{a_i})^s$, where $a_i$ is a finitely supported function $I \to \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$. By Nakayama's lemma, it is enough to show that $R^s/R^{s+1}$ is generated by these elements. We have
$$(1-\prod_i g_i^{a_i})^s = (1-\prod_i (1+t_i)^{a_i})^s \equiv \left( \sum a_i t_i \right)^s \bmod R^{s+1}.$$
So our generators are $s$-th powers of linear forms, and $R^s/R^{s+1}$ is the degree $s$ polynomials; this is exactly what our lemma addresses. $\square$

Comment: Suppose $p>2$ and consider the truncated polynomial algebra $A=k[x,y]/<x^p,y^p>$. I am probably missing something, but it seems to me that your answer would imply that $Rad(A)^2$ is generated as an ideal by the elements $x^2$ and $y^2$. Is this really the case? What about the element $xy\in Rad(A)^2$?

Comment: No, it is generated as an ideal by all the squares, $(ax+by)^2$. To be concrete, $xy = \tfrac{1}{2} \left( (x+y)^2 - x^2 - y^2 \right)$.

Comment: Sure, I see this, but your original statement seems to be different to me. Note that for the 2-generated elementary abelian group we  have that $kG$ is isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: As you say, let $A$ be the elementary abelian group of order $p^2$, with generators $u$ and $v$, and let $x = u-1$ and $y = v-1$, then $kA \cong k[x,y]/\langle x^p, y^p \rangle$. Then $xy \equiv \tfrac{1}{2} \left( (uv-1)^2 - (u-1)^2 - (v-1)^2 \right) \bmod \langle x,y \rangle^3$.

Comment: Ok, thanks: I see the point.

Comment: You were right and I modified my post accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Under these assumptions, note that $\mathrm{Rad}(kG)$ coincides with the augmentation ideal $\omega(kG)$ of $kG$. Now, as remarked by Jeremy Rickard, the question is equivalent to whether the elements $(g-1)^s$ with $g\in G$ generate $\mathrm{Rad}^s(kG)$ as an ideal of $kG$. Theorem 3.7 in Section 5.3 of the book [D.S. Passman: *The algebraic structure of group rings*] provides an explicite description of $Rad(kG)^s$ for all $s>0$. As proved in the beautiful David's answer, $Rad(kG)^s$ is in fact generated by the elements of the form $(g-1)^s$ with $g\in G$ in the given situation.